# Change generated action bar theme from Android Asset Studio

Tags: android, user-interface, android-actionbar

I have used Android Asset Studio to generate action bar style, however i woul like to do some changes, which I was unable to do in Studio, so I edited generated theme but lot of things was just ignored, and I just can't figure out how things work. 
There is example:
`

```
<style name="Theme.Myactionbar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_myactionbar</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Myactionbar</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Myactionbar</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Myactionbar</item>
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Myactionbar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Myactionbar</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_myactionbar</item>
    <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_myactionbar</item>
    <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Myactionbar</item>


</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Myactionbar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_myactionbar</item> //THIS IS GREEN 
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_solid_myactionbar</item>//THIS IS GREEN
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_myactionbar</item>//THIS IS GREEN
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Myactionbar</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Myactionbar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_transparent_myactionbar</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Myactionbar</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu.Myactionbar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu">   
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_example  </item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownListView.Myactionbar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_myactionbar</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Myactionbar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_myactionbar</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownNav.Myactionbar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_myactionbar</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_myactionbar</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_myactionbar</item>
</style>

<style name="ProgressBar.Myactionbar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_myactionbar</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.Myactionbar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionButton.CloseMode">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_myactionbar</item>
</style>

<!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
<style name="Theme.Myactionbar.Widget" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Myactionbar</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Myactionbar</item>
</style>
```

Everything was like in generator, but then i tried the simplest change, that is the color, so I edited style name=ActionBar.Solid.Myactionbar  and put there som other drawables from other generated style. 
It looked like this :

```
    <style name="Theme.Myactionbar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_myactionbar</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Myactionbar</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Myactionbar</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Myactionbar</item>
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Myactionbar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Myactionbar</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_myactionbar</item>
    <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_myactionbar</item>
    <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Myactionbar</item>


</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Myactionbar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_example</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_example</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_myactionbar</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Myactionbar</item>
</style>
```

but nothing happend, and changed drawables supposed to be gray. I was wandering if anybody did this before and why this isnt working? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out, there is values-v14 folder for styles for api level 14 and above, so you have to change these values too.